# Multiple sliders and Multiple button. But the Output is the same page

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe df . The requirement is once I select the input range from the slider and then click on update the table should be updated, There are 2 sliders and 2 actions button. For example if select input ranges for MOnday and click Mon_Update the table should get updated(No matter what input values are there for Tuesday) SImilarly if I select Input values for Tuesday and select Tue_Update the table should be updated

```
     library(shiny)
      library(ggplot2)

       df <- structure(list(Col = 1:11, Mon = c(47L, 110L, 31L, 72L, 129L,
                                     41L, 85L, 123L, 14L, 152L, 118L), Tue 
      = c(164L, 168L, 146L, 140L,

       185L, 77L, 26L, 15L, 23L, 116L, 101L), Wed = c(163L, 5L, 109L,

       170L, 37L, 96L, 41L, 188L, 163L, 82L, 5L), Area = structure(c(1L,

        1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B",

       "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Street = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L,

       1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Ste 1", "Ste 2"), 
       class =

       "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,

       -11L))
       ui <- fluidPage(
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Week",titlePanel(h4("Trend of
                                        Consumption",align="center")),
                   sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(selectInput("plot","plot",choices = 
       c("","display")),
                                  sliderInput("range", label = h6("Mon"), 
         min= min(df$Mon),max = max(df$Mon),
                                              value = c(min(df$Mon),  
         max(df$Mon))),
                                  actionButton('clickme', label = 
          h6("Mon_Update")),
                                  sliderInput("range1", label = h6("Tue"), 
           min= min(df$Tue),max = max(df$Tue),
                                              value = c(min(df$Tue),  
            max(df$Tue))),
                                  actionButton('clickme1', label = 
            h6("Tue_Update")),
                       uiOutput("area"),uiOutput("street"),width = 2),
                     mainPanel(plotOutput("graph"),
                               dataTableOutput("graph1")
                               )
                     )
                   ))
        )

     server <- function(input, output, session) {
 selectedData <- eventReactive(input$clickme,{
  df[ df$Mon %in% input$range[1]:input$range[2],]
})
graph1 <- reactive({
  if (input$plot == "display") {
    selectedData()
  }
})
output$graph1 <- renderDataTable(
  {
    graph1()
  }
)
selectedData1 <- eventReactive(input$clickme1,{
  df[ df$Tue %in% input$range1[1]:input$range1[2],]
})
graph1 <- reactive({
  if (input$plot == "display") {
    selectedData()
  }
})
output$graph1 <- renderDataTable(
  {
    graph1()
  }
)
    }

       shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since in your selectedData you use:

```
df[ df$Mon %in% input$range, ]
```

you have only the values that are equal to `input$range`.

Two approaches I can think of are:

a) change your code to  keep all the values between 1 and the `input$range`,i.e.:

```
 df[ df$Mon %in% 1:input$range, ]
```

b) use the input as a range input, i.e. providing a range of values:

```
sliderInput("range", label = h6("Range"), min= min(df$Mon),max = max(df$Mon),
               value = c(min(df$Mon),  max(df$Mon)))
```

and update the selectedData to:

```
selectedData <- reactive({
df[ df$Mon %in% input$range[1]:input$range[2], ]
})
```

Comment: what is the error that you see in the console. It is weird, since for me is working with both options.

Comment: @DevP, if you went straight for option 2, I have updated also my answer.

Comment: @NP it is working fine. Can I ask one question. I tried that but not getting, Can we add one actionbutton so that once I click only the table should get changed. So it should work this way. I select input values from slider and then click on action button, After this only the table should get reflected

Comment: you can achieve this, by adding an action button in your ui:
 ````actionButton('clickme', label = h6("Update"))```` and updating the selectedData from ````reactive```` to ````eventReactive```` in your server that is:
`````selectedData <- eventReactive(input$clickme,{
    df[ df$Mon %in% input$range[1]:input$range[2], ]})`````

Comment: Thanks and it is working. I am facing few challenges and sorry I did not know this would occur. I have edited my question for you. Now I have 2 sliders and 2 buttons corresponding to each day. When I select input values for MOnday and click Mon button the table should get reflected(Irrespective of values under Tuesday). When I select input values for Tuesday and click Tue button the table should get reflected(Irrespective of values for Monday)

Comment: Imho this is not the right way to go. I would create a dropdown list, of which dimension you want to change. Then I would use this input to update the selectedData. So with one dropdown, one range and one button, you get the flexibility you want.

Comment: DId not get you? Can you please edit the code for me please?

Comment: I got your point little. So what if the range of dimensions are different; For example for Mon(SAy it is 1 to 100) and for Tue(Say it is 500 to 1000) In this case?

Comment: you have to update the sliderInput by using ````updateSliderInput````

Comment: Here the problem the dimensions are column wise and we can render the table as per the dimension

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199185/discussion-between-dev-p-and-npt).